# Tom is taller than I?

Tags: pronouns, subjects, comparative

In [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23535/tom-and-i-or-tom-and-me), in one of the comment threads the following was stated

> Tom is taller than me" or "Tom is taller than I am" — both are correct. "Tom is taller than I" is WRONG` ([link](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23535/is-it-i-or-me-in-keep-tom-and-i-me-updated#comment44273_23536))

Which I'd agree with. This comment is disputed with

> That is very arguable. More used? Definitely. Wrong? Not if you consider "than" as being a conjunction, in which case the last part of the phrase "Tom is taller than I [am tall]" is elided.

So is it really grammatically acceptable to use the following?

> Tom is taller than I

Comment: see [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3447/i-can-run-faster-than-1-him-2-he) for more info

Comment: Also see http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/60289/28962 and http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11102/than-i-am-vs-than-me.  In short, **she is taller than he (is), so I like her more than (I like) him**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“...than I am” vs. “...than me”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11102/than-i-am-vs-than-me)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If I is some physical unit, variable, or measure, it might - or might not - be correct.
Grammatically, you have to use an object pronoun. me, you, him, etc. This is quite standard, me thinks.

But have a look at:
http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/than-i-versus-than-me

Comment: Do you mean ___I___ as meaning iodine, for instance? Grammatically, any common or proper noun can be the object; it only matters for pronouns.

Comment: I enjoyed the linked article particularly and I fall definitely into the Conjunctionist group.. the semantic distinction between "Aardvark likes Squiggly more than I/me" is useful and intuitive I find.. Nice to now be able to make a grammatical argument for it.

Comment: Excellent source, but from that article I would conclude that both "Tom is taller than me" and "Tom is taller than I" are correct, with the latter being slightly preferable.

Comment: @Voo From a logical point of view, it makes perfect sense, to use the same pronoun, whether the whole sentence is spoken or whether 'am (tall)' is only muttered, swallowed or whatever. But Grammar has a lot to to with how a language is generally used.

Comment: Even 'Me thinks' might become correct again someday...

Comment: Interesting side note: Judging from the 2 other languages I know and from some google translating of languages I know less, I have found that ONLY ENGLISH seems to have this particular problem. The other languages seem pretty conjunctionist...

Answer (score 2):

If *than* is a conjunction, use **than
I**. If it's a preposition, use **than me**. The less formal, but common one is **than me**, and the more formal is **than I** which means **than I am tall.**

Comment: Can you provide examples for both cases?

Answer (score 1):

"Tom is taller than I" is traditionally considered correct according to prescriptive grammar. Because of this, I don't think it would generally be considered wrong by educated individuals, although you're free to have the opinion that it's wrong. It's certainly not what comes naturally to most English speakers (possibly not what comes naturally to any of them), and it tends to sound pretentious/stuffy.

There's a good summary at the following ELU question: [I can run faster than _____. (1) him (2) he?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3447)